# Rating is not showing on review block

Tags: frontend, review, ratings

Customer can leave **review (name, comment)** but the **rating** (which can **mark 1 ~ 5 star**) is **not showing on review block** at the product page

**Mage_Rating** is enable on **System - Advanced**

What should I check more to enable the ratings to be seen on the frontend product page?

Comment: Did you checked whether the rating is enabled in your store.
Go to catalog -> reviews and ratings - > Manage ratings
select any of the predefined ratings and check whether its selected for your store.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to catalog -> reviews and ratings - > Customer Reviews->pending reviews
and make status to approved.Now you can see all reviews on product page.

Comment: I mean Customer can leave review but can not mark the rating ( 1 ~ 5 star ) when leave since it's not show on front-end, pending and approve works well

Comment: Hi,Go to catalog -> reviews and ratings - > Manage ratings,  You willl find here Price ,Quality and Value, NOw click on price,you will see here option 
Rating Visibility->Visible in  and select default store View  and now save rating.Now for same for quality and value.Hope This will help

Comment: If we are using new theme how can i add the rating code to product view.phtml?

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2 & upper version follow the below guidelines

- Go to `Admin panel >> Marketing >> Reviews`
- To edit the comments & customer reviews listed there **click edit**
- In the status make it approved from pending

Your Ratings & reviews are going to be displayed on the product page